# Appeal Play Home

Tags: baseball

Sitch:
We have a R3 who missed home plate, what's the ruling?
If the runner is scrambling back to the plate, is a tag appeal of the runner the only option offered to defense? Can they not tag the plate if the runner is scrambling back, regardless of how low it took said runner to start scrambling? Or can any fielder tag the plate immediately?

Also I read on Umpire Manual that *in that case, the runner must be tagged. In such cases, base path rules still apply to the runner*. But how would it be applied? Can runner avoid to be tagged going back more than 3 feet backwards? I mean he can not go 3 feet to the left or to the right but, once he missed homeplate, could you go backwards, to avoid the tag, more than 3 feet or what?

Comment: Is this a force play at home?